# no able to install packages as wireshark

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

Since a month, I can not download package of Ubuntu Software 14.10
This is really annoying. I try to type the command : `sudo apt-get update`

But I have this result:

```
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg
Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic InRelease

Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic-updates InRelease

Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic-backports InRelease

Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic-security InRelease

Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic Release.gpg
  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »
Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic-updates Release.gpg
  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »
Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic-backports Release.gpg
  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »
Err http://mirrors.compuscene.org utopic-security Release.gpg
  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-fr_FR
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-fr
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic/InRelease  

W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/InRelease  

W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/InRelease  

W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/InRelease  

W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release.gpg  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »

W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/Release.gpg  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »

W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/Release.gpg  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »

W: Impossible de récupérer http://mirrors.compuscene.org/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/Release.gpg  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « mirrors.compuscene.org »

W: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
root@generation_zen:/home/trackpower# sudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list

(gedit:7292): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: Just a hint for your next question: You can prepend `LANG=C` to a command (separated by a space) to make it temporarily output its error and status messages in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is trying to download its package lists from `mirrors.compuscene.org`, which appears to be offline at the moment (the domain name cannot be resolved to an IP address).

Edit your apt sources:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove all lines that contain `mirrors.compuscene.org` and add the following lines:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run another `apt-get update` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank's you very much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!